# Best practices for querying tables residing in different database using JOIN statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello and thank you very much for your time. I am using SQL Server 2008. My challenge is as follows:

I have 3 databases `Q_DB`, `CAN_DB`, `USA_DB`. `CAN_DB` and `USA_DB` have the same tables but represent two different countries

The `Q_DB` has tables of queues. One table is called `ACCOUNTS` and the columns of interest are `ACCOUNTID` and `SERVER`

I want to query the information on the other two databases from the fields of `ACCOUNTS`. An example is:

**Q_DB.dbo.ACCOUNTS**

- ID123    CAN_DB
- ID456    USA_DB
- ID789    CAN_DB

I know I can do it this way, but it I was wondering if there is any other approach to obtain the result.

```
SELECT ACTNAME, AMTDUE, SHIPCOUNTY  
FROM CAN_DB.dbo.Accts 
WHERE ACCTID IN(SELECT ACCOUNTID FROM Q_DB.dbo.ACCOUNTS WHERE SERVER IN('CAN_DB')
UNION ALL
SELECT ACTNAME, AMTDUE, SHIPCOUNTRY 
FROM USA_DB.dbo.Accts
WHERE ACCTID IN(SELECT ACCOUNTID FROM Q_DB.dbo.ACCOUNTS WHERE SERVER IN('USA_DB')
```

Any help or opinions or suggestions would be greatly appreciated . Thanks

Comment: So you are saying you want to UNION the results of two different queries, and you are wondering if there is a better way to do it than using a UNION?  I'm not sure what you are expecting.

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2010** - there's versions 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2 and 2012 - but no 2010 version.... so which one are you really using??

Comment: I am trying to see if Using WHERE with the UNION is the smartest approach or if using a different method I can take away the UNION (since i am basically rewriting the code over)
And thanks for your time

Comment: Sorry that was supposed to be 2008

Comment: @jnoel10 The fact is, there are 2 different tables, in 2 different databases.  You need to union them.  They way you are doing it is fine.  However, I would question that specific WHERE.  Do you expect the USA_DB to have an ACCTID with a SERVER other than USA_DB?

Comment: @cadell0 Thanks for the response, I am not 100% certain I understand the question, but CAN_DB and USA_DB possibly have the same ACCTID however they are referring to different accounts and that is why I add the WHERE SERVER = 'USA_DB' portion to make sure I am getting the correct entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why you are using `IN` with a single value (`CAN_DB`).

Also, you should precognize `EXISTS` instead of `IN`.

```
SELECT ACTNAME, AMTDUE, SHIPCOUNTRY  
FROM CAN_DB.dbo.Accts a1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Q_DB.dbo.ACCOUNTS WHERE ACCTID = a1.ACCTID AND SERVER = 'CAN_DB')
UNION ALL
SELECT ACTNAME, AMTDUE, SHIPCOUNTRY 
FROM USA_DB.dbo.Accts a2
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Q_DB.dbo.ACCOUNTS WHERE ACCTID = a2.ACCTID AND SERVER = 'USA_DB')
```

Note: Using `UNION ALL` will return duplicates (if there are some). To have the query select unique rows, use the keyword `UNION` instead.

EDIT: If you want to sum the `AMTDUE` from both servers according to same `ACTNAME` and `SHIPCOUNTRY` :

```
SELECT  COALESCE(can.ACTNAME,usa.ACTNAME) as ACTNAME,
        COALESCE(can.AMTDUE,0)+COALESCE(usa.AMTDUE,0) as AMTDUE,
        COALESCE(can.SHIPCOUNTRY,usa.SHIPCOUNTRY) as SHIPCOUNTRY  
FROM    CAN_DB.dbo.Accts can
FULL OUTER JOIN USA_DB.dbo.Accts usa
ON      can.ACTNAME = usa.ACTNAME AND 
        can.SHIPCOUNTRY = usa.SHIPCOUNTRY
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I agree that EXISTS looks much better than IN. I was trying to see if there is a way i could call this without using the UNION at all. The reason I use the UNION ALL is due to the fact that it is possible that I will have duplicate ACCTIDs but from the different servers

Comment: Are the duplicate `ACCTID` related with each other? if so, it can be done using a `JOIN`... I guess you'd want to sum the `AMTDUE` from both servers according to same `ACCTID` and `SHIPCOUNTRY` ?

Comment: Sadly they may not be related (it is a data integrity issue that I will also be resolving but is slow going) and that is why I did not use JOIN, but I am a novice to SQL and still learning :)

Comment: Ok, I understand the `ACCTID` is not the same, but could the `ACTNAME` be the same?

Comment: They can be different meaning,  ACCTID and ACTNAME can be the same on both servers, and ACCTID can be the same on both but the ACTNAMEs can be different. I hope this helps

Comment: Also I used the EXISTS instead of the IN and looks much cleaner and makes more sense.

Comment: I added a solution to SUM values from both servers.

Comment: As for `EXISTS` instead of `IN`, it is much more performant to use `EXISTS`. `IN` would select every row of the table and then compare the returned IDs versus `EXISTS` will stop selecting as soon as 1 row, satisfying the condition, is returned.

Comment: Than you for all your help Francis